# File upload not working more than 10mb in AWS Linux 2 server?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

When I try to upload a video more than 10mb server show error of *502* I have changed in the php.ini file also and phpinfo also reflect the change

```
    post_max_size 40M
    upload_max_filesize 35M
    max_execution_time 1200
    max_input_time
```

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }

    ?>
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's a problem of file size? Maybe your request is too long (longer than Nginx timeout)

Comment: No, when I upload the video of 5mb its working fine when upload 10mb its show "is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 502" and i am useing "amzn2-ami-hvm" server

Answer (score 0):

Do you use API Gateway? It has 10Mb limitation on payload size. Please see:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: No, I am not using API Gateway.